# Converting a date in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to convert one date in different formats:
Below is the example-
There is one field named as ****APRVL_DT**** and lets take 3 values of this column are

```
APRVL_DT
18-JUN-12 09.25.34.000000000 AM
02-JUL-12 09.46.42.000000000 AM
16-JAN-14 09.54.26.000000000 AM
```

not sure about the timezone.It may be UTC.
Now i want to convert this fields in the format where i'll get data according to daylight saving.So Output should be

```
New_APRVL_DT
18-JUN-12 01.25.34.000000000 PM
02-JUL-12 01.46.42.000000000 PM
16-JAN-14 02.54.26.000000000 PM
```

I written one code which is giving me data but not in daylightsaving format-

```
TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ (TO_TIMESTAMP (APRVL_DT , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'EST5EDT') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS A.M.') As NEW_APRVL_DT
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: You seem to have a timestamp rather than a date, and neither has any inherent format - Oracle stores them in an internal representation and your client formats them as a readable value. But you don't appear to want a different output format, you just want to adjust the time zone; but then you say "not sure about the timezone", which is rather important. What data type is the `APRVL_DT` column?

Comment: You say "not sure about the timezone.It may be UTC." In this case it will be very difficult to run any conversion. In case it it really UTC, then it would be the other way around, i.e. `FROM_TZ (APRVL_DT, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT'`

Comment: What is the data type of `APRVL_DT`? In case it is `TIMESTAMP` (as it looks like) then `TO_TIMESTAMP` is pointless.

Comment: APRVL_DT has EST timezone.Could you now adjust the timezone so that i can get desired output

Comment: Please edit your question to include the column's data type - which you've now said elsewhere is a string; clarify which way the conversion is going - as it actually seems you want EST/EDT to UTC; and include the output from your attempt, or the error it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to convert a string representing a plain timestamp that you know represents an EST/EDT time to UTC (though the description in the question and your conversion attempt contradict each other). You really should not be storing dates or timestamps as strings, but if that is what you are stuck with, you just need to convert to (and from) the right data type. So you can do:

```
select APRVL_DT,
  TO_CHAR(
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(
      FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(APRVL_DT, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM'), 'America/New_York')
    ), 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') AS NEW_APRVL_DT
from your_table
```

```
APRVL_DT                        NEW_APRVL_DT
------------------------------- -------------------------------
18-JUN-12 09.25.34.000000000 AM 18-JUN-12 01:25:34.000000000 PM
02-JUL-12 09.46.42.000000000 AM 02-JUL-12 01:46:42.000000000 PM
16-JAN-14 09.54.26.000000000 AM 16-JAN-14 02:54:26.000000000 PM
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a29d07a5ff21d0ad5497b894af9a3aa)

Although that is essentially what your attempt was already doing...

If your session date language doesn't, or might not, match the language used for the month abbreviations in your table then you can specify that in the query:

```
select APRVL_DT,
  TO_CHAR(
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(
      FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(APRVL_DT, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'), 'America/New_York')
    ), 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS NEW_APRVL_DT
from your_table
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fef0d84038ce01b695ae1b31500d918)

Comment: It is not returning the data in daylight saving format.

Comment: @Milanchaudhary - it's giving the result you showed in your question. What do you mean by 'format' - do you want to see whether it was originally EST or EDT in the output, even though it's not UTC? You didn't show or say that. Or do you not actually want the UTC time, just the original time with an EST/EDT marker?

Comment: Hey @AlexPoole your data is correct. I want in this format only. But now problem is APRVL_DT is a String so We have to convert this into timestamp so that we can use other function on that.

Comment: @Milanchaudhary - well, that's what your original query attempt was doing; except the first conversion format model doesn't match your sample data, so would have thrown ORA-01830. So it's now even less clear what you are really asking.

Comment: ,i am using your last provided code but i am getting ORA-01843: not a valid month error.

Comment: That could be a language mismatch - I've added how to avoid that if so - but one of the downsides of storing dates/timestamps as strings is that you might end up with data in formats you don't expect. Or, the data in your table just isn't as you showed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> There is one field named as `APRVL_DT` [...] not sure about the timezone. It may be UTC.
>
> Now i want to convert this fields in the format where i'll get data according to daylight saving.

You have the time zones in the wrong order:

```sql
SELECT APRVL_DT,
       FROM_TZ( APRVL_DT, 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT' As NEW_APRVL_DT
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( aprvl_dt TIMESTAMP );

INSERT INTO table_name ( aprvl_dt )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-06-18 09:25:34.000000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-06-02 09:46:42.000000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2014-01-16 09:54:26.000000000' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> APRVL_DT                      | NEW_APRVL_DT                     
> :---------------------------- | :--------------------------------
> 2012-06-18 09:25:34.000000000 | 2012-06-18 05:25:34.000000000 EDT
> 2012-06-02 09:46:42.000000000 | 2012-06-02 05:46:42.000000000 EDT
> 2014-01-16 09:54:26.000000000 | 2014-01-16 04:54:26.000000000 EST
> ```

---

From this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650903/converting-a-date-in-oracle/66652249#comment117822838_66650903):

> `APRVL_DT` has EST timezone.

```sql
SELECT APRVL_DT,
       FROM_TZ( APRVL_DT, 'EST' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT' As NEW_APRVL_DT
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> APRVL_DT                      | NEW_APRVL_DT                     
> :---------------------------- | :--------------------------------
> 2012-06-18 09:25:34.000000000 | 2012-06-18 10:25:34.000000000 EDT
> 2012-06-02 09:46:42.000000000 | 2012-06-02 10:46:42.000000000 EDT
> 2014-01-16 09:54:26.000000000 | 2014-01-16 09:54:26.000000000 EST
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f2800c0cc72e2e7f1f239fdd1b6ac1a)*